# I'm having trouble with tomcat 8 at my server

Tags: tomcat8

I'm having a problem with my Application. At my local machine it works fine, but when I upload it to the server (runs Tomcat 8 with JDK 8) it doesn't work. And there's nothing in the logs.

I need some help, because I don't know what's happening.

Comment: Searching trought the Stackoverflow, I just find a similiar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688960/tomcat-unable-to-start-with-app-deployed

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more details, at least regarding how your deployment is made. Do you copy a `.war` built with `maven` in the `/webapps` directory ? What command line do you use to start your server ? Is the `.war` getting correctly exploded ? Or do you simply copy classes in a directory under `/webapps` ?

I'll provide more info (and hopefully a solution) once the post is clarified :)

Comment: Sorry about that, i'm using Ivy as framework and vaadin. I build the war, and copy/paste to the server, and run a .bat.
But when I try to conect to the URL, nothing happening, just the loading bar keeping rolling

Comment: Do you use a .war file ? Is it getting exploded ("extracted") by Tomcat at startup ? Does the content of the .war file look correct (for example you have a web.xml in the WEB-INF directory ? Since you have nothing in logs one could suppose that you don't provide an adequate file format, but you don't give alot of info :P Don't hesitate to edit your post as much as necessary

Comment: Yes, I use a .war file, and it was correct (the content).
I just uptaded from tomcat 7 to tomcat 8, and JDK 7 to JDK 8, and since this, I'm getting trouble with this and the log just show the application is running without errors, but at my local machine works fine

Comment: Supposing that you still have your tomcat 7 installation (just a directory.. If it is in trash restore it :), if you use the exact same war with the V7, does it get exploded correctly at startup ? Also did you update relevant environment / path variables ? Your JAVA_HOME might have changed since you updated from JDK7 to JDK 8

Comment: But when I tried to use tomcat 7 and i get a message like "can not compile with 52.0, this is java 7 (something like that) ", so when I updated the tomcat, didn't show anymore but my application doesn't work.

Comment: Your tomcat version has nothing to do with compiling your code. If you are not sure about the conditions / error messages, I can't do more, sorry (I already did more than I should given the format of your question ;) )

Comment: Thank's for your help!

Comment: NP. Reproduce issues, note error messages, take as much info as you can, then create a clean new post with all the info, I'm sure we'll be able to help you then :)

Comment: Niilzon! I found the error, it was a param in Tomcat config, something like "uploadTimeOut" I just deleted this, and it's working! Thank's for helping!

Comment: @RaphaelVieiraRossi ahah glad you found the Way :)